# different result of int multiplication vs float multiplication

Tags: java, floating-point, int, floating-accuracy, floating-point-conversion

I have this code:

```
    float number1 = 2f / 12;
    System.out.println(number1);
    int number2 = 6;
    float x = number1 * number2;
    System.out.println(x);
```

And as output I get:

```
0.16666667
1.0
```

Why? When I multiply number1 and number2, number2 should be promoted to float type, and I should get a 0.96

When I modify my code to:

```
    float number1 = 0.16f;
    System.out.println(number1);
    int number2 = 6;
    float x = number1 * number2;
    System.out.println(x);
```

I get good result:

```
0.16
0.96
```

Why operation `float = float * int` in first example produces the bad result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> number2 should be promoted to float type

Number 2 *got* promoted to float.

> and I should get a 0.96

You should get 1.0, because:

2 / 12 * 6 = 2 / 2 = 1

0.16 * 6 = 0.96

... and that's *why*. It has nothing to do with computational int vs float arithmetic in this case, it's just arithmetic. Do the math first!

Comment: dear downvoter, would you care to elaborate on the deficiencies of this answer?

Answer (score 2):

Because in **second case** you defined:

```
float number1 = 0.16f;
//0.16*6=0.96;
```

But for the **first case** you have:

```
2 / 12 = 0.166666667    
0.166666667*6=1
```